# findString program python

Tags: python

I have an assignment said that to create a findString function that accept 2 string which are 'target' and 'query', and that returns  a  list  of  all  indices  in  target  where  query  appears.  If  target  does  not  contain  query, return  an  empty  list.

For example:
findString(‘attaggtttattgg’,’gg’)

return:

[4,12]

I dont know how to start off with this function writing at all. Please help me everyone. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: homework? There is a homework tag, FYI.

Comment: I have added "homework" tag. If it is not, please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> def find_string(search, needle):
>       start = -1
>       results = []
>
> ```
> while start + 1< len(search):
>     start = search.find(needle, start +1)
>
>     if start == -1:
>         break
>
>     results.append(start )
>
> return results
> ```

Comment: It should be noted that the find method is deprecated in 3.0.

Comment: thank you very much but as we input search and needle into that (), does it mean to make this function to accept 2 arguments right? Sorry for asking this but I am totally a newbie to python and programming. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

since an answer has already been given:

```
def find_matches(strng, substrng):
    substrg_len = len(substr)
    return [i for i in range(len(strg) + 1 - substrg_len) 
            if strg[i:i+substrg_len] == substrg]
```

Comment: def find_matches(strg, substr):
    substrg_len = len(substr)
    return [i for i in range(len(strg)+1 - substrg_len)
            if strg[i:i+substrg_len] == substr]

Comment: Annyway this is i think a better solution than mine :)

Comment: @armonge: yours is very good too, I like both :) thanks guys a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of hints to get you started.

1. [`target.find(query)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) will return the index of `query` in target. If `query` is not found, it will return -1.
2. A string can be sliced. `target[pos:]` will give you a substring of target starting from `pos`.

Answer (score 0):

This may require some error handling:

```
def find_allPatterns(strVal, strSub):
    listPos = []
    strTemp = strVal

    while True:
        try:
            posInStr = strTemp.index(strSub)
        except ValueError:
            posInStr = None
        if posInStr:
            listPos.append(posInStr)
            subpos = posInStr + len(strSub)
            strTemp = strTemp[subpos:]
        else:
            break

    return listPos

print find_allPatterns('attaggtttattgg', 'gg')
```

Output:

```
[4, 6]
```